# Pass the correct constructor Parameter when creating an instance from class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following class Component: **`EmployeeComponent`** which I use in other class **`ExampleDataSource`** as super class and inherit a method and properties from it. At the end I'am also creating an instance in **`TableEmployees`** from **`GenerateDataSource`** with the `new` operator in order to pass `dataSoure`.

The issue is that when creating the instance form `TableEmployees`, a parameter is expected (which make sense). I tried to pass: `this.dataSource` but ng test throws following error: 
**`Property 'dataSource' does not exist on type 'EmployeeComponent'.`**

**`employee.component.ts`:**

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public empService:EmployeesService, public http:Http) {}
    ngOnInit() { this.getEmployees(); }

    getEmployees() {
       this.empService.getUsersList()
       .subscribe(
            (res) => {
            this.userGetData = res.message;
           },(err) => {
              this.errorMessage = err;
           }
        )
    }
}

export class TableEmployees {
    displayedColumns = ['uid', 'email', 'name'];
    dataSource = new GenerateDataSource(//HERE I'VE TO PASS THE PARAMETER );
}

export class GenerateDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

    constructor(public usrComponent:UsersComponent){
        super();
    }
    connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
        alert(this.usrComponent.userGetData);
        return Observable.of( this.usrComponent.userGetData );
    }
    disconnect() {}
}
```

dataSource is being used in: **`employess.component.html`**:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
      <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ...
      ...
      </mat-table>
</div>
```

Comment: The GenerateDataSource class seems to have a constructor which takes in the UsersComponent as the parameter. Should you not pass that component while creating `new GenerateDataSource(// COMPONENT)`?

Comment: My Bad... changed the name of the component class but didn't change it `GeneratedDataSource`. I apologize! Should be: `constructor(public usrComponent:EmployeeComponent){ super(); }
    connect(): Observable<Element[]> { return Observable.of( this.usrComponent.userGetData ); }`